# How to use OData in a Asp.Net Core Razor Page Project (without MVC, API)

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, razor-pages

Is there a way to use OData in a Asp.Net Core Razor Pages? I have found many implementation examples for .Net Core MVC or API projects, but i cant find any examples for Razor Pages.

Comment: You can include API controllers in a Razor Pages project. But the Razor Pages themselves are designed to generate HTML.

Comment: Yeah that was the approach i tried today and it worked. I thought there might be a better one

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [OData documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/) - OData (Open Data Protocol) is an ISO/IEC approved, OASIS standard that defines a set of best practices for building and consuming REST APIs. It enables the creation of REST-based services which allow resources identified using Uniform Resource Locators (URLs) and defined in a data model, to be published and edited by Web clients using simple HTTP messages. Razor pages are not suitable for REST API development. ASP.NET Core WEB API or MVC is a better choice for building RESTful applications.